# SQL Select with root parent

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I have a table Members(id, name, parent_id), where parent_id is the parent of the member(it is also a member which can have its parent). For example

```
id | name | parent_id
----------------------
1  | John | NULL
2  | Smith| 1
3  | Andy | 1
4  | Joe  | 2
5  | Rick | 2
6  | Craig| 5
7  | Greg | NULL
8  | Bob  | 5
9  | Mike | 8
```

And I'd like to run statement select from members, and I want to have

```
id | name | parent_id | root_parent_id
--------------------------------------
1  | John | NULL      | NULL
2  | Smith| 1         | 1
3  | Andy | 1         | 1
4  | Joe  | 2         | 1
5  | Rick | 2         | 1
6  | Craig| 5         | 1
7  | Greg | NULL      | NULL
8  | Bob  | 7         | 7
9  | Mike | 8         | 7
```

I want to find the root_parent_id for all members as deeply as possible. Help me please

Comment: mysql ?  sql? or Postgresql?

Comment: Postgresql is a must. Thanks

Comment: then remove the other tags please ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with recursive recursive_members as (
    select *, id root_id, 1 depth
    from members
union all
    select r.id, r.name, r.parent_id, m.parent_id, r.depth+ 1
    from recursive_members r
    join members m on r.root_id = m.id
    where m.parent_id notnull
)
select distinct on (id) *
from recursive_members
order by id, depth desc;

 id | name  | parent_id | root_id | depth 
----+-------+-----------+---------+-------
  1 | John  |           |       1 |     1
  2 | Smith |         1 |       1 |     2
  3 | Andy  |         1 |       1 |     2
  4 | Joe   |         2 |       1 |     3
  5 | Rick  |         2 |       1 |     3
  6 | Craig |         5 |       1 |     4
  7 | Greg  |           |       7 |     1
  8 | Bob   |         5 |       1 |     4
  9 | Mike  |         8 |       1 |     5
(9 rows)
```

Read about [recursive WITH queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html).